# WOPI wdl* query params injected into middle of redirect URL

Tags: office365, ms-wopi

I have been working on a WOPI solution and have recently seen some weird behavior where the wdl* query parameters are getting injected into the middle of the call back URL.

In the network tab of the F12 developer tools I see the following request

[https://office.live.com/start/Word.aspx?h4b={Company](https://office.live.com/start/Word.aspx?h4b=%7BCompany) Name and Product}&c4b=2&eurl=https://{Server}/#/microsoft-office/123073&hp=6sW5SZo+fQ4SiPRE+M3+XzLmJ9KpwpvL5xYrse8+zPY=

Which results in a 302 redirect. The issue is the location header has the following URL.

https://{Server}/?wdlcs=gY4CMRNo7lOyF6Xi7B7I3Y1fPBiRf8klKh/cwfOZkOQ=&wdlcsexp=637618892956193570#/microsoft-office/123073

As you can see the two wdl query parameter were injected into the middle of the callback url.

I did notice that is appears that they were injected right before the "#" in the callback URL. However I have not been able to find any documentation that says that the "#" is unsupported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug in the MS WOPI implementation that is unresolved at the moment. It was scheduled for fixing early January 2022, but the status of the fix is currently unknown.

Comment: I found the issue on github but forgot to copy the URL here.

Comment: Microsoft have released another fix for this today. Please test again and see if the problem is fixed!

Comment: Hi @NickMcKenna, don't you know if this was fixed also on staging environment? After logging in microsoft account is my host page always redirected to itself with different wdlcs string, but the content is never loaded.

Comment: I can see in the CSPP Yammer group that this issue was confirmed as resolved (by users) on 28th February 2022. It was tested by MS in test/staging, so I would expect it to be working! If you think it's still a problem, the best thing to do is create a Fiddler trace with session id and submit a support ticket to MS (you'll need to be a CSPP member to do this).